# how to capture the event of a manual click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am manually calling the click event of an input type: file.

**HTML**

```
<input onChange={this.displayFilePath} className="invisible" type="file" id="logo"/>
```

**JS**

```
 $('#logo').click();
```

If I was NOT calling the click event manually in the javascript, I could capture the file data within the click event method like so:

```
let file = event.target.files[0];
```

So my question is:  By operating the click event manually, How do I capture the `event` it throws so that I can strip off the file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `event.currentTarget` inside the handler should suffice.

Comment: don't use click. use change. click event will be called before a file is even selected. change will be called when the actual file has been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
$('#logo').click(function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    //whatever you want with the event 
});
```

Although asked about click event you could use

```
$('#logo').on("change", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    //whatever you want with the event 
});
```

change will allow you to capture details about the file after it has been selected instead of calling the function when the input button is clicked.

Comment: It will subscribe to click event, which will not have access to `files` collection. So probably not what OP needs.

Comment: I'm using ReactJS, so I didn't use an anonymous function, but this concept got me to the finish line.  Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!